# Android - A way to trigger onRetainNonConfigurationInstance?

Tags: android

Is there a way to trigger the calling of onRetainNonConfigurationInstance on my activity, so getLastNonConfigurationInstance() returns something the next time the activity is created?

I ask because I have a memory leak in my application which only appears/crashes my app after my phone is left idle for hours, so I believe the issue is here.

Force Stop in Settings does not cause this. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i've spent days chasing red herrings to catch this bug.

Comment: Figured it out, I just need to rotate the screen.

Answer (score 0):

if you are having memory leaks I suggest that you manage those memory leaks instead of forcing the rotate of the screen.